# check NSDate in month

Tags: nsdate

I have NSDate object and I need to find from a NSArray (that has nsdate objects) all objects that have the same month and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This earlier answer shows you how to get the month and day information. You can use it to do what you are asking:

[NSDate get year/month/day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day)